# How to use transfer function in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

I created smart contract to transfer ETH from one account to another, ETH deduction occurs but send to other address(which is not specified). Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract ETH{
    address public  buyer;
    uint public amt;
    address public seller;
    constructor(){
        seller = msg.sender;
    }
    function add(address payable _buyer) payable public{
        buyer = _buyer;
        payable(buyer).transfer(amt);
    }
    function bal() view public returns(uint){
        return buyer.balance;
    }
    function s() payable public returns(uint){
        return msg.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of `amt` is 0 and your code does not set this property (to a non-zero value) anywhere.

Which effectively makes your `.transfer(amt)` function to send 0 ETH to the `buyer` and keep all the ETH, that you sent along with the transaction, in the contract.

If you want to redirect the sent amount, there's the `msg.value` global variable, which reflects the current value sent with the transaction.

```
payable(buyer).transfer(msg.value);
```